# How to setup squid proxy with multiple 3g modems?

Tags: proxy, squid

I have 3 USB dongles on my computer. How do I setup squid to proxy each port to the appropriate dongle?

So I will have 3 virtual networks, with default gateways. I'm looking for squid directive to proxy

```
3128 -> x.x.x.x(first gateway)
3129 -> y.y.y.y(second gateway)
3130 -> z.z.z.z(third gateway)
```

I found config for 3proxy

```
auth strong
users login:password
users login1:password1
users login2:password2
users login3:password3
allow login,login1
socks -n -a -p3281 -i192.168.0.2 -e192.168.1.2
proxy -n -a -p3282 -i192.168.0.2 -e192.168.1.2
flush

allow login2,login3
socks -n -a -p3283 -i192.168.0.2 -e192.168.1.3
proxy -n -a -p3284 -i192.168.0.2 -e192.168.1.3
flush
```

But how to do it in squid?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: Added what I have, but didn't really find the solutions, that's why asking.

Comment: Run three squids, each gouing out via distinct gateway.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov, I believe it should be possible with one instance of squid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t even need multiple Squid instances to do this.

The three building blocks are as follows:

- the listening port
- Squid ACLs
- the outgoing address

Squid can listen on multiple ports using multiple [`http_port`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/http_port/) directives. You can also assign these ports names for brevity.

[Squid ACLs](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl) can be used to match the proxy port the client connected to (`myport` and `myportname`).

The outgoing address for various protocols can be set. You’re most likely interested in [`tcp_outgoing_address`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/tcp_outgoing_address/). It can be linked to an ACL. Note the additional restrictions, in case you have more configuration.

In case you *do* want multiple Squid instances, you can just use `tcp_outgoing_address`.

In addition, you *may* have to set up policy routing, based on the source address, but that shouldn’t generally be necessary.